# How to generate full pdf using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm trying to print Invoice in my application, using **html2canvas** along with **jspdf**.
This is my code-

```
    private download(): void {

      let options = {
        pagesplit: true,
        background: '#fff',
        format: 'PNG',
        padding: 50,
        margin:{top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 10, useFor:'page'}
      };

      const input = document.getElementById("content");

      html2canvas(input)
          .then((canvas) => {
              const pdf = new jsPDF("pt", "px", "a4");
              pdf.addHTML(input, 20, 10, options, () => {
                  pdf.save("invoice.pdf");
              });
          });

    }
```

The code works, but the PDF being printed is only of the viewport screenshot. Whatever view part of invoice coming in scroll sections would be printed rest won't be printed. I wanted to print the complete invoice and not the part appearing in the viewport screenshot.

What changes do I need to make. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only targeting printing and not saving pdf file. You should use `print` media query and use browsers in built print mechanism triggers on `ctrl + p` on windows and `cmd + p` on Mac.

There are few problems with `jspdf`, like it will refetch all the remote images while generating PDF. That won’t happen with `printcss` or print media query.

Comment: I want to **save(download)** the PDF as well, `ctrl + p` is not an option in my application. thanks!

Comment: @VijaySharma, Why did not you use [autoPrint()](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-autoprint.html#~autoPrint)